# kubernetes nginx ingress server-snippet annotation not taking effect

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have following ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: nginx-configuration-snippet
    annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
          location /base/path/v1/api/update {
              deny all;
              return 404;
            }
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /base/path(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: myApi
              servicePort: 8080
```

But when I send PUT request to /base/path/v1/api/update instead of getting 404 I am getting 500 which means that the path is reachable from ingress controller. Can anybody help me identify why ?

I changed to configuration-snippet and the error I got is :

```
Error: exit status 1
2020/08/06 18:35:07 [emerg] 1734#1734: location "/base/path/v1/api/update" is outside location "^/base/path(/|$)(.*)" in /tmp/nginx-cfg008325631:2445
nginx: [emerg] location "/base/path/v1/api/update" is outside location "^/base/path(/|$)(.*)" in /tmp/nginx-cfg008325631:2445
nginx: configuration file /tmp/nginx-cfg008325631 test failed
```

Comment: Did you pull down the generated `nginx.conf` and ensure it was written in the place you expected? Also, and this is kind of pedantry, [the fine manual](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-snippet) says "once per host" but you don't have a host -- so, it's possible they just noped right out (hopefully logging something in the controller logs)

Comment: yeah it no oped. Any idea on how else to achieve this ?

Comment: One way is to actually declare a `host:` value, and see if that makes it less angry, the other is to use the [`server-snippet:`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#server-snippet) *ConfigMap* setting

Comment: Actually I added more description, I tried configuration-snippet and it seems like it's not a no op anymore. But now getting error. Not able to understand the error though

Comment: Well, did you copy the generated config out of the controller pod and look at it? nginx configuration is a wild and mysterious land, but without looking at the config file, there's no way anyone can *guess* what's wrong

Comment: yeah, I don't have access to nginx.conf currently. Let me get it from someone

Comment: Did you manage to solve problem ?

Comment: yes added answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding my own answer :
The final config that worked for me was :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: nginx-configuration-snippet
    annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
          location ~* "^/base/path/v1/api/update" {
              deny all;
              return 403;
            }
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /base/path(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: myApi
              servicePort: 8080
```

Comment: Another solution is to use the `^~` location modifier in the snippet, e.g. `location ^~ /base/path/v1/api/update`, which tells Nginx to prefer the match over regex locations (slightly more efficient).

Answer (score 1):

Just for other coming along here looking for a solution, worth knowing that snippets are ignored unless the nginx controller is started with the `-enable-snippet` option on the command line. It should be noted that this applies to `nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress` project.

The [docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests#3-deploy-the-ingress-controller) say:

> Before creating a Deployment or Daemonset resource, make sure to
> update the command-line arguments of the Ingress Controller container
> in the corresponding manifest file according to your requirements.

For instance if you are running the Daemonset, you will have to edit the `sudo nano kubernetes-ingress/deployments/daemon-set/nginx-ingress.yaml` manifest and add your argument as shown below:

```
        args:
          - -nginx-configmaps=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-config
          - -default-server-tls-secret=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-server-secret
          - -enable-snippets
         #- -v=3 # Enables extensive logging. Useful for troubleshooting.
         #- -report-ingress-status
         #- -external-service=nginx-ingress
         #- -enable-prometheus-metrics
         #- -global-configuration=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-configuration
```

Also check other `Command-line Arguments` in [the docs here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/global-configuration/command-line-arguments/#-enable-snippets)

If you are looking for helm follow this [guide in the docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: how to enable it if using manifest, e.g., kubectl apply -f ...